# Given $G = (V, E)$, is there a spanning tree $T$ such that $\deg_G(v)=\infty\implies\deg_T(v)=\infty~\forall v\in V$?

Tags: graph-theory

Every connected graph has a spanning tree, [even the infinite ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree#In_infinite_graphs), and I think that is pretty neat.

To build the spanning tree of a graph, you might have to discard some of its edges. You might even be forced to discard edges incident on a finite-degree vertex, what would certainly reduce its degree, which is a shame. Infinite-degree vertices, however, can maintain their degree even after the removal of several of its incident edges. So here is my question:

Given some graph $G = (V, E)$, is there a spanning tree $T$ of $G$ such that $\deg_G(v)=\infty\implies\deg_T(v)=\infty~\forall v\in V$?

I'm mostly interested in the countable case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### In the countable case, the answer is yes.

Let $v_1, v_2, v_3, \dots$ be the vertices of infinite degree, and let $w_1, w_2, w_3, \dots$ be the vertices of finite degree. Our goal is to satisfy the following infinite set of conditions:

1. For all $i \ge 1$ and $j\ge 1$, $\deg_T(v_i) \ge j$.
2. For all $i \ge 2$, there is a path from $v_i$ to $v_1$.
3. For all $i \ge 1$, there is a path from $w_i$ to $v_1$.
4. The graph has no cycles.

There are countably many conditions listed out under items 1-3, so we can list them all out in order and try to satisfy them, one at a time, while not violating item 4. Let $F_n$ be the subgraph of $G$ we have after satisfying the first $n$ conditions on our list; for all $n$, $F_n$ is a forest with finitely many edges.

We must show that when we get to the $n^{\text{th}}$ condition on our list, it is possible to add finitely many edges to $F_{n-1}$ to get a new subgraph $F_n$ that also satisfies the new condition, and still has no cycles. There are two cases:

- When we get to a condition of the form $\deg_T(v_i) \ge j$, we will satisfy it (or rather, satisfy $\deg_{F_n}(v_i) \ge j$) by adding up to $j$ edges from $v_i$, using only edges to vertices $x$ with $\deg_{F_{n-1}}(x) = 0$. This ensures that we create no cycles. We can always find such edges in the graph, because $\deg_G(v_i) = \infty$, and there are only finitely many vertices with nonzero degree in $F_{n-1}$.
- When we get to a condition which wants a path from some vertex $x$ to $v_1$, we begin by finding a path from $x$ to $v_1$ in $G$. Then we go through the edges of this path one at a time, and add them if they do not create cycles. If an edge would create a cycle, then that means its endpoints are already in the same connected component, so it's not necessary. After we're done, all vertices of the path are in the same connected component of $F_n$ one way or another, so in particular there is a path from $x$ to $v_1$.

Now let $$T = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n,$$ taking all the edges present in $F_n$ for any $n$. Since $F_n$ satisfies the first $n$ positive conditions on our list, $T$ must satisfy all of them, so $T$ is connected and $\deg_T(v_i) = \infty$ for all $i \ge 1$.

On the other hand, $T$ still cannot have cycles. Suppose there were a cycle in $T$ with edges $e_1, e_2, \dots, e_k$. Then for each $i=1,\dots,k$ there is some $n_i$ such that edge $e_i$ is contained in $F_{n_i}$. Let $n = \max\{n_1, n_2, \dots, n_k\}$; then $F_n$ already contains all $k$ edges, so there would be a cycle in $F_n$, which we made sure would not happen.

#### In the uncountable case, this is not necessarily possible.

Define a bipartite graph with vertices $v_1, v_2, v_3, \dots$ on one side; on the other side, for each infinite subset $S \subseteq \{1,2,3,\dots\}$, add a vertex $w_S$ adjacent precisely to the vertices $v_i$ with $i \in S$. In this graph, every vertex has infinite degree, so we'd like a spanning tree $T$ where every vertex has infinite degree.

Take any infinite set $S$, and let $S' = \{i \in S : v_i w_S \in E(T)\}$: the set indexing all the neighbors of $w_S$ in $T$. Because $S'$ must be infinite, there is also a vertex $w_{S'}$ in our graph, which must also have infinite degree. In particular, $w_{S'}$ must have degree at least $2$. But any two neighbors $v_i, v_j$ of $w_{S'}$ are also neighbors of $w_S$ in $T$, and the four vertices $w_S, v_i, w_{S'}, v_j$ form a $4$-cycle in $T$. So the tree isn't a tree after all.

Comment: In fact, if $G$ is a connected bipartite graph with bipartition $V_0,V_1$ where $V_0$ is countable and $V_1$ is uncountable, and if $T$ is a spanning tree of $G$, then all but countably many vertices in $V_1$ are leaves of $T$. For, if for uncountably many vertices $v\in V_1$ there is a $2$-element set $X_v\subseteq N_T(v)$, then uncountably many of them have the same $X_v$, so $K_{2,\aleph_1}\subseteq T$.